# Native-Module can not be Null when launching react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, mobile-application

I want to build existing react-native app on ios simulator. It shows build is successfull but the App is not launching and crashed the App. It shows the given Error.

> **Native module can not be null**

[image]

please someone help me to find out the solution of the given problem. I am getting stuck for long time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of your dependecies or your node_modules folder, try running npm install or npm i on terminal

Comment: i tried it many times but don't fix the problem which i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping me.
I fix the above problem by uninstalling Push Notifaction and Geolocation and react-native-vectors-icons and then install again react-native-vector-icons and boom..!!!
my ios application is running on my xcode simulator.